# With a 5000x20 CSV as data input discover the most common occurrences of numbers in a row

Tags: statistics, orange, numerical

As input I have a CSV with 5000 lines (and growing) and 20 fixed columns containing a number from 1-80.

A row may look like this.

[image: Sample CSV]

Is it possible using Orange3 to analyze each row and find out what pairs, tripes, quads, quints, etc. occur the most often on a row?

The output I am looking to get is "these 2 numbers occur the most often on a row" "These 3 numbers occur the most often on a row", "These 4 numbers occur most often on a row" etc, etc... up to 10 numbers that occur the most often on a row.

While I do know the numbers that occur the most frequently, I am untrained on how to determine the pairs, and up.

If so what direction should I head in, and which widgets should I be concentrating on? Any other information to help me learn the knowledge to perform the task?